# Wrapping pointer-to-pointer in Fortran C binding

Tags: c, fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

I would like to call the C function `posix_memalign` in Fortran to get memory which is aligned safely for SSE or AVX. Its prototype is:

```
int posix_memalign(void **memptr, size_t alignment, size_t size);
```

Using the Fortran 2003 C binding, how do I wrap the pointer-to-pointer? I would like to convert the void pointer to an array using `c_f_pointer`.

Comment: You could just write a wrapper that returns the single pointer.

Comment: Worst case scenario, you can just create aligned regions in Fortran, by allocating `alignment-1` extra bytes and adjusting the beginning to be aligned.

Comment: @Oppen In theory I could write a C wrapper, but unfortunately there's no C building machinery in the project. For the second option, how do I measure alignment in fortran?

Comment: Maybe you could use `aligned_alloc` instead, then. As for pointers in Fortran, I'm assuming they behave similarly to C (I haven't used Fortran), in the sense that they support arithmetic operations and can be converted to integers. If that's true, you can take do something analogous to the following C code: `p = ((intptr_t)p+alignment-1)&~(alignment-1)`, assuming alignment is a power of 2 (which it should for your use case), where `p` is the previously allocated region with padding.

Comment: @Oppen Pointers in Fortran do not support pointer arithmetic. Tricks can be done using `transfer()` but it is not standard conforming.

Comment: @VladimirF sad, but I guess it makes sense. Pointer arithmetic is the source of many evils, and specifically aliasing (I read somewhere Fortran doesn't allow pointer aliasing, is that right?).

Comment: Anyway. Does `aligned_alloc` suit your needs? It doesn't have the double-pointer parameter issue, it works quite like `malloc` instead. Here's the manpage: https://linux.die.net/man/3/aligned_alloc

Comment: @Oppen, I'm not sure what the "double-pointer parameter issue" is, in terms of using the resulting allocated memory, but a Fortran dummy argument `type(c_ptr) memptr` matches the `void **memptr` of the C prototype.

Comment: @francescalus does a dummy argument work there? It's precisely the actual output, the return value is only to check for success. Also, OP asks precisely how to wrap that argument. Maybe I'm misunderstanding what you mean by "dummy" here?

Comment: @Oppen, the dummy argument in the Fortran interface would correspond to the formal parameter of the C prototype. On return, the C address of the Fortran pointer type would be that of the newly allocated memory.  You can read more about C interoperability in Fortran in the tag info for [tag:fortran-iso-c-binding].

Comment: OK, then I'm not understanding why you call it "dummy". But nevermind, it's a pointless semantic discussion.

Comment: @Oppen A dummy argument is the Fortran standard terminology for what the C standard calls a formal parameter.  That's all there's to it. Pointer aliasing is allowed in Fortran. Non-pointer non-target argument aliasing is not allowed.

Comment: Oh, thanks @VladimirF.